# ASP.NET Core Routing works in VS IIS Express but not in IIS 10

Tags: c#, rest, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I am developing ASP.NET Core web API. here I have a situation like I have to use multiple `get` functions which get data from SQL server DB. So for that, I'm doing custom attribute routes. below are my codes

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITechRepository _tech;
    private readonly IPageOptions _page;
    public MeController(ITechRepository tech,IPageOptions page)
    {
        _tech = tech;
        _page = page;
    }

   [Route("getTech")]
    public IEnumerable<TechStack> Get()
    {
        return _tech.getAll();
    }
    [Route("getOptions")]
    public IEnumerable<PageControl> getOptions()
    {
        return _page.getOptions();
    }
     //GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public int Get(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The above routes are works well in VS IIS Express and this is that URL

```
http://localhost:51889/api/me/gettech
```

But when i publish this API in IIS 10. The `getTech` and `getOptions` were not working it producing `404` error and also `[HttpGet("{id}")]` is working in both.

Can anybody help on this...

Comment: plz provide more information, what kind of error, do you get? which http response codes? Btw. I suppose to define the HttpMethod instead of using to convention over configuration approach...
and further I'm not familiar with .net core web api, but I wonder why you're inheriting from COntroller and not from ApiController.

In fact I would guess that it's not worling, just because you use a lower case method name

Comment: @DotNetDev Thank you for your comment. There is no apiController class in asp.net core.

Comment: can anybody help on this

Comment: What happens ich you're call http://youredomain/gettech Maybe you're custom route "gettech".  Even if its easier to start with IIS express Ich would always prefer IIS as it is also a good mirror of you're production environment

Comment: @DotNetDev It gives me 404 Error...

Comment: you could try out with swashbuckle to get your controller swagger definitions and see if it's deployed in general

Comment: @DotNetDev Thank you. I fixed this and i will update my answer by end of the day.

Comment: The issue was in sql server login.

Comment: @DotNetDev i have updated the answer. Thanks for your advises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got the issue fixed.

The problem was in the login of SQL server. I configured my application in IIS 10  in the my own Application Pool named **aspNetCore**. Its configurations are

> .Net CLR version : **No managed code**
>   Managed pipelined mode : **Integerated**
>   Identity : **ApplicationPoolIdentity**

Identity cause the issue.

When i call this URL http://localhost:51889/api/me/gettech the IIS try to login into the SQL Server with the Login Id of **IIS Apppool / aspNetCore**. Then ended up with the following error

> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\AspNetCore'. Reason: Could not find
>   a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

I captured the above issue in Event Log with Event ID : 18456

For this I have to create the Local User and group for this identity. Unfortunately i can't able do this because i'm using Windows 10 Home edition. which does not allow me to do this.

what i did is create the Custom Identity for my Application pool(aspNetCore).

[image]

[image]

There I gave Username, password of the account which is already found in my user groups as well as SQL Server. And i gave `dbowner` rights to this account for my db.

[image]

But still i don't know why it returned 404 error.

Anyhow, The issue was fixed now.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: thank you this helped me. I used my own windows account

Answer (score 3):

For web api use the `Http{Verb}` attribute with route template for controller actions as mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing)

> **Tip:**
>   When building a REST API, it's rare that you will want to use
>   `[Route(...)]` on an action method. It's better to use the more specific
>   **[Http*Verb*Attributes]** to be precise about what your API supports.
>   Clients of REST APIs are expected to know what paths and HTTP verbs
>   map to specific logical operations.

For example...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MeController : Controller {
    private readonly ITechRepository _tech;
    private readonly IPageOptions _page;
    public MeController(ITechRepository tech,IPageOptions page) {
        _tech = tech;
        _page = page;
    }

    //GET api/me/tech
    [HttpGet("tech")]
    public IEnumerable<TechStack> Get() {
        return _tech.getAll();
    }

    //GET api/me/options
    [HttpGet("options")]
    public IEnumerable<PageControl> getOptions() {
        return _page.getOptions();
    }

    //GET api/me/5
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public int Get(int id) {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response... But it still not working... same behavior. This is my url - http://localhost/testApi/api/me/tech which is not working

Comment: As I said, http://localhost:51889/api/me/tech this IIS Express url is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have fixed this issue.

Comment: what was the answer ?