# No access to database when publishing web-api to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, iis, deployment

I have a Rest-api in asp.net which gets data from a database (mydb) from a server (myServer1)

If I start the API in Visual Studio I have access to the database on "myServer1"

If I deploy it to my local IIS (7) I have access to the database on "myServer1"

If I deploy it to the IIS on "myServer1"(IIS 8) the website and the swagger ui is correctly shown, but when I try to get data the Error 500 is displayed. I already tried to rename  the server in the connection string from "myServer1" to "localhost" when deploying on "myServer" but no success

What am I missing?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43052305/2131576

Comment: Not the same problem but similar. I had to change Identity to LocalSystem then i got a more detailed error wich was solved by installing the same MySqlConnector version on my pc and on the server